# states/regions not loading at checkout for guests or registration in opencart

Tags: opencart

im having a Opencart 1.5.4 installed... there is this problem where the users/guests are unable to register at the checkout because the states are not being populated based on the country...

when a user registers at the register page it works but not at the checkout..

Below is the JS i think which populates the states in the checkout/register.tpl..

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#payment-address select[name=\'country_id\']').bind('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/checkout/country&country_id=' + this.value,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#payment-address select[name=\'country_id\']').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.wait').remove();
        },          
        success: function(json) {
            if (json['postcode_required'] == '1') {
                $('#payment-postcode-required').show();
            } else {
                $('#payment-postcode-required').hide();
            }

            html = '<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>';

            if (json['zone'] != '') {

                for (i = 0; i < json['zone'].length; i++) {
                    html += '<option value="' + json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] + '"';

                    if (json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] == '<?php echo $zone_id; ?>') {
                        html += ' selected="selected"';
                    }

                    html += '>' + json['zone'][i]['name'] + '</option>';
                }
            } else {
                html += '<option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_none; ?></option>';
            }

            $('#payment-address select[name=\'zone_id\']').html(html);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});

$('#payment-address select[name=\'country_id\']').trigger('change');
//--></script>
```

when i check in firebug this code doesnt run at all... nothing happens.. atleast it doesnt show me an error.

the similar code at the registration page works without any problem.

You can have a look at my cart website http://tinyurl.com/oup3hsv

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update files in checkout folder.

First of all, download default Opencart 1.5.4 Source from official [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=download/download) site.

**Copy files from default source**
Go to default OpepnCart source `catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\` then copy following files.

- guest.tpl
- guest_shipping.tpl
- payment_address.tpl
- payment_method.tpl
- shipping_address.tpl
- shipping_method.tpl

**Replace files in your site source**
Go to Your site source `catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\` then Replace above files.

& then check it.

Comment: Thanks... i did a full replace of the checkout files... but still it doesnt work :(

Comment: are you use any cache plugin? if, Yes. So, please remove it plugin cache. if, You have use vqmod plugin. So, please remove vqmod cache & then try check it.